# mongodb migration with ts-migrate-mongoose package

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I am developing a nestjs application. I am using ts-migrate-mongoose for db migration. In my migration files I have imported a user schema from outside of the migration folder(which is in the root folder by default).
When I import with an absolute path it cant resolve the path and gives error

`import { UserModel } from 'src/modules/user/repository/user.model';`

`Error: Cannot find module 'src/modules/user/repository/user.model'`

But when I use a relative path like the following, it gives error after going into the user model file where I have another import with an absolute path

`import { UserModel } from '../src/modules/user/repository/user.model';`

Works fine until in user model file I have an import like this

`import { User, UserStatus } from 'src/entity/user.entity';`

Now it cant resolve another absolute path. In this case, I would have to remove all the absolute imports, which I don't think is a feasible solution.

in my ts-config file i have the baseUrl set to './'

I tried uninstalling and installing the package, expected it to work, i also tried installing it as a global package.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/ilovepixelart/ts-migrate-mongoose) of ts-migrate-mongoose says you need to add `.swcrc` to the project root, as the package uses swc to compile typescript. Give that a go if you haven't already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open and issue on github [here](https://github.com/ilovepixelart/ts-migrate-mongoose/issues)

But try to follow this example if you have issue with your setup:

- [ts-express-swc](https://github.com/ilovepixelart/ts-express-swc)